# How should I broadcast with MPI if I want to compute the sum across multiple processors?

Tags: c, memory, parallel-processing, mpi, assertion

I am starting to get into parallel computing, and have started with MPI using C. I understand how to do such a thing using p2p (send/recv), however my confusion is when I try to use collective communication with bcast and reduce.

My code goes as follows:

```
int collective(int val, int rank, int n, int *toSum){
        int *globalBuf=malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        int globalSum=0;
        int localSum=0;
        struct timespec before;

        if(rank==0){
                //only rank 0 will start timer
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &before);
        }
        int numInts=(val*100000)/n;
        int *mySum = malloc((numInts)*sizeof(int *));

        int j;
        for(j=rank*numInts;j<numInts*rank+numInts;j++){
                localSum=localSum+(toSum[j]);
        }

        MPI_Bcast(&localSum, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Reduce(&localSum, &globalSum, n, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if(rank==0){
                printf("Communicative sum = %d\n", globalSum);
                //only rank 0 will end the timer
                //an display
                struct timespec after;
                clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &after);
                printf("Time to complete = %f\n",(after.tv_nsec-before.tv_nsec));
        }
}
```

Where the parameters being passed in can be described as:

```
val = the number of total ints that need to be summed - divided by 100000
rank= the rank of this process
n = the total number of processes
toSum = the ints that are going to be added together
```

Where I begin to run into errors, is when I try to broadcast this processors ***localSum*** to be handled by rank 0.

I will explain what I've put into the function call so you can possibly understand where my confusion comes from.

For MPI_Bcast:

```
&localSum - the address of this processes sum
1 - there is one value that I want to broadcast, the int held by localSum
MPI_INT - meaning implied
rank - the rank of this process that is broadcasting
MPI_COMM_WORLD - meaning implied
```

For MPI_Reduce

```
&localSum - the address of the variable that it will "reducing"
&globalSum - the address of the variable that I want to hold the reduced values of localSum
n - the number of "localSum"s that this process will reduce (n is number of processes)
MPI_INT - meaning implied
MPI_SUM - meaning implied
0 - I want rank 0 to be the process that will reduce so it can print
MPI_COMM_WORLD - meaning implied
```

When I look through the code, I feel it makes sense logically, and it compiles okay, however when I run the program with m amount of processors, I get the following error message:

```
Assertion failed in file src/mpi/coll/helper_fns.c at line 84: FALSE
memcpy argument memory ranges overlap, dst_=0x7fffffffd2ac src_=0x7fffffffd2a8 len_=16

internal ABORT - process 0
```

Can anyone help me find a solution? Apologies to anyone who see's this as second nature, this is only my third parallel program, and first time using bcast/reduce!

Comment: Yes, because I have an "array of int pointers", and I want to allocate enough memory for n int pointers, I think.

Comment: please post a [mcve], it is currently impossible which data you want to reduce and where it is located when the subroutine is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues in the call of collective operations (`MPI_Bcast`, `MPI_Reduce`) provided in your code. First in `MPI_Reduce`, you are reducing an integer `localSum` from every processes to an integer `globalSum`. Basically, a **single** integer. But in your `MPI_Reduce` call, you are trying to reduce `n` values, in reality you just need to reduce **1** value from `n` processes. That may cause this error.

The reduce should ideally be like this, if you want to reduce a single value:

```
    MPI_Reduce(&localSum, &globalSum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

For the broadcast,

```
    MPI_Bcast(&localSum, 1, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

every rank is broadcasting above in your call. According to the general idea of broadcast there should be one **root** process that should broadcast the value to all the processes. So, the call should be like this:

```
    int rootProcess = 0;
    MPI_Bcast(&localSum, 1, MPI_INT, rootProcess, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Here, the `rootProcess` will send the value contain in its `localSum` to all the processes. Meanwhile all the processes calling this broadcast will receive the value from `rootProcess` and will store in its local variable `localSum`